# Rails 4 - How to get last row of data inside the scope?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, scope

In rails 4, I want to get the last row of data inside scope. I have models called `Abc`, `AbcRoot`, `AbcRootDisabling` and inside `Abc` model,

```
def self.including_abc_disablings
   joins('JOIN abc_roots_abcs as crc ' \
          'ON crc.abc_id = abcs.id').
        joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_root_disablings as disablings ' \
          'ON crc.abc_root_id = disablings.abc_root_id')
end

private_class_method :including_abc_disablings

scope :not_disabled, -> {
  including_abc_disablings.where(disablings: { id: nil })
}
```

Here, `abc` has_many disablings, while checking a condition inside the scope I need to take last row of disablings and I need to check like `disablings.id` is nil or `disablings.enabled_at` is not `nil`.

How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: There is no such thing as "last row" until you *specify the ordering explicitly*. Could you please specify what is "last disabling" in your case (_which field you order by_)?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to get the "last" record, according to some definition (e.g. `created_at`) of last would be:

```rb
including_abc_disablings.where(disablings: { id: nil }).order(created_at: 'desc').limit(1)
```

in other words, sort with most recent first, and take the first record.